# Can You Set Up Android Studio/SDK Manager to check for/get the latest rev of AWS SDK for Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, sdk, android-studio

So I'm going to start experimenting with AWS SDK for Android from Amazon and while I imagine it's quite stable and bug free by this point, I want to setup my environment (Android Studio) to check for the latest version of AWS SDK for Android just in case there are package updates while developing. I looked around on the [AWS SDK for Android SDK getting started page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/gsg/Welcome.html) and there doesn't seem to be anything about this described, even for working in Eclipse which I know should support this kind of functionality.

Is it even possible with Android Studio and the SDK Manager to be setup such that it checks for the latest packages of the AWS SDK, does Amazon host their SDK for Android somewhere it's pullable from in such a fashion, and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: For it to work with the SDK Manager, there should be an `addon.xml` file somewhere. While Amazon provides this for the Kindle USB driver, I couldn't find an equivalent one for AWS for Android. Neither is there a Maven repository, apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So really your best bet here is to pick the current SDK build and stick with it. You aren't exactly sure what they might change, and it might have unexpected issues in your code. Even when you use a dependency management like Maven, you rarely change the version of your dependencies.

But, if you want to stay up to date, your best bet is to check it out from their GIT repo, and stay current that way.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android

It provides you a link to this repo here...
http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/

Comment: With the Gradle build system, we're moving more toward not using the + syntax in version numbers for libraries or the plugin and making users specify explicit version numbers instead. Using explicit version numbers prevents the problem of your build mysteriously not working (or acting different) when a version of something changes, often without your knowledge. We (the Android Studio team, and me personally) have been guilty of some of this, because the tooling often uses + syntax in its generated code, but we're fixing that.

Comment: It seems to get what I want Amazon would have to post AWS SDK for Android on Maven Central like they have for Java for me to pull it through SDK Manager. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/16